# multimap predicate using lambda

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, lambda

I am trying to sort some relational data using a multimap but am having issues getting the predicate defined correctly.

```
  std::multimap<
      std::vector<Message>, std::string,
      bool (*)(const std::vector<Message>, const std::vector<Message>)>
  sortmap([&](const std::vector<Message> &lhs,
              const std::vector<Message> &rhs) {
    return lhs.size() < rhs.size();
  });
```

The types seem to be correct but visual studio says otherwise.

Comment: is that closing `>` in the right place?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: I think he wants to create an object of type multimap<...> named sortmap using the ctor that takes a comparator as first argument. not sure though. an ssccee would be needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll go through some of the options mentioned:

**Option 1** @Joachim Pilborg

```
  auto comparator = [](const std::vector<Message>& lhs,
    const std::vector<Message>& rhs) {
    return lhs.size() < rhs.size();
  };

  std::multimap<std::vector<Message>, std::string, decltype(comparator)> sortmap(comparator);

  Message msg;
  std::vector<Message> messages;
  messages.push_back(msg);

  std::string str;
  auto test = std::make_pair(messages, str);

  sortmap.emplace(test);
```

results in

```
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\xtree(1007): error C3497: you cannot construct an instance of a lambda
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\xtree(1006) : while compiling class template member function 'main::<lambda_2efe1f793bd1dfe8b84381ab9a3a87dc> std::_Tree_comp<false,_Traits>::_Getcomp(void) const'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Traits=std::_Tmap_traits<std::vector<Message,std::allocator<Message>>,std::string,main::<lambda_2efe1f793bd1dfe8b84381ab9a3a87dc>,std::allocator<std::pair<const std::vector<Message,std::allocator<Message>>,std::string>>,true>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\xtree(1789) : see reference to function template instantiation 'main::<lambda_2efe1f793bd1dfe8b84381ab9a3a87dc> std::_Tree_comp<false,_Traits>::_Getcomp(void) const' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Traits=std::_Tmap_traits<std::vector<Message,std::allocator<Message>>,std::string,main::<lambda_2efe1f793bd1dfe8b84381ab9a3a87dc>,std::allocator<std::pair<const std::vector<Message,std::allocator<Message>>,std::string>>,true>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\xtree(1024) : see reference to class template instantiation 'std::_Tree_comp<false,_Traits>' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Traits=std::_Tmap_traits<std::vector<Message,std::allocator<Message>>,std::string,main::<lambda_2efe1f793bd1dfe8b84381ab9a3a87dc>,std::allocator<std::pair<const std::vector<Message,std::allocator<Message>>,std::string>>,true>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\map(275) : see reference to class template instantiation 'std::_Tree<std::_Tmap_traits<_Kty,_Ty,_Pr,_Alloc,true>>' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Kty=std::vector<Message,std::allocator<Message>>
1>  ,            _Ty=std::string
1>  ,            _Pr=main::<lambda_2efe1f793bd1dfe8b84381ab9a3a87dc>
1>  ,            _Alloc=std::allocator<std::pair<const std::vector<Message,std::allocator<Message>>,std::string>>
1>          ]
1>          c:\users\c\documents\visual studio 2013\projects\project1\project1\source.cpp(15) : see reference to class template instantiation 'std::multimap<std::vector<Message,std::allocator<_Ty>>,std::string,main::<lambda_2efe1f793bd1dfe8b84381ab9a3a87dc>,std::allocator<std::pair<const _Kty,std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>>>>' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ty=Message
1>  ,            _Kty=std::vector<Message,std::allocator<Message>>
1>          ]
```

**Option 2** @PlasmaHH

```
  std::multimap<
      std::vector<Message>, std::string,
      bool (*)(const std::vector<Message> &, const std::vector<Message> &)>
  sortmap([&](const std::vector<Message> &lhs,
              const std::vector<Message> &rhs) {
    return lhs.size() < rhs.size();
  });
  Message msg;
  std::vector<Message> messages;
  messages.push_back(msg);

  std::string str;
  auto test = std::make_pair(messages, str);

  sortmap.emplace(test);
```

This DOES compile, but strangely leaves an error in visual studios error list (and leaves an annoying red squiggle):

```
1   IntelliSense: no instance of constructor "std::multimap<_Kty, _Ty, _Pr, _Alloc>::multimap [with _Kty=std::vector<Message, std::allocator<Message>>, _Ty=std::string, _Pr=bool (*)(const std::vector<Message, std::allocator<Message>> &, const std::vector<Message, std::allocator<Message>> &), _Alloc=std::allocator<std::pair<const std::vector<Message, std::allocator<Message>>, std::string>>]" matches the argument list
        argument types are: (lambda []bool (const std::vector<Message, std::allocator<Message>> &lhs, const std::vector<Message, std::allocator<Message>> &rhs)->bool)  c:\Users\c\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Project1\Project1\Source.cpp   12
```

}

I instead settle with

```
  auto comparator = [](const std::vector<Message> &lhs,
    const std::vector<Message> &rhs) {
    return lhs.size() < rhs.size();
  };
  std::multimap<std::vector<Message>, std::string,
    std::function<bool(const std::vector<Message> &,
    const std::vector<Message> &) >>
    sortmap(comparator);
  Message msg;
  std::vector<Message> messages;
  messages.push_back(msg);

  std::string str;
  auto test = std::make_pair(messages, str);

  sortmap.emplace(test);
```

Option 1 appears not to work:

https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/727957/vc11-beta-compiler-fails-to-compile-lambda-key-comparer-for-maps-and-sets

explicitly defining the type works, and using std::function for some reason makes the (annoying!!) red squiggle and error list entry go away. Hope this helps!

Comment: I am also dealing with the same problem. Thanks for the nice discovery about the compiler bug, I think I will make the workaround by using the good ol' `struct` for comparison.

Answer (score 4):

A lambda can be used in place of a function pointer, but a lambda is not a function pointer. Therefore the type of the third template argument is wrong.

Instead you could define the lambda first, and use e.g. `decltype` to get the lambda type. Something like the following code:

```
auto comparator = [](const std::vector<Message>& lhs,
                     const std::vector<Message>& rhs) {
    return lhs.size() < rhs.size();
};

std::multimap<std::vector<Message>, std::string, decltype(comparator)> sortmap(comparator);
```

Comment: A noncapturing lambda can decay to a function pointer, and thus be passed as a parameter where such a function pointer is expected. (5.1.2-6)

Comment: Firstly I'd never heard of decltype which seems like it will be my new friend in the future. But I would like to ask why   auto comparator2 = [](const std::vector<Message>& lhs,
    const std::vector<Message>& rhs) {
    return lhs.size() < rhs.size();
  };

  std::multimap<std::vector<Message>, std::string, bool(*)(const std::vector<Message>&, const std::vector<Message>&)> sortmap(&comparator2); doesnt work. Or is there no way to pass the lambda as pointer?

Answer (score 4):

Your comparator template parameter type is

```
bool (*)(const std::vector<Message>, const std::vector<Message>)
```

while the type the lambda can decay to is

```
bool (*)(const std::vector<Message>&, const std::vector<Message>&)
```

I suggest you make the multimap take references in its comparator parameter too.

Comment: My original code looked as such, unfortunately I was shotgunning a few approaches before I posted here as a last resort :)

Comment: @user193138: Well, it works that way: http://ideone.com/TEkNFU so if your original code looked that way, but did not work, something else must have been wrong that we can't see.

Comment: Note that this is MSVC 2013. I was not using my code isolated. The code you gave actually shows an error (a red squiggle), but proceeds to compile anyways. The 'error' is http://pastebin.com/nwCWgSuH. I think this is a visual studio specific issue.

Comment: @user193138: If you have a new question, please ask it as a seperate one. This time please include a complete [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) that people can take and feed into their compiler (or additionally try things out yourself on ideone.com). This helps seeing what is going on.